# Stop Magento from cleaning phone number in checkout

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, onepage-checkout

How can I stop Magento from removing special chars like comma from telephone number during checkout?

I looked in OnepageController.php leading to `Model/type/Onepage.php` but could not find where  phone number is cleaned up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out input was filtered by the browser (safari only) because in the template file `onepage\billing` we had `<input type="number" ...>`. This is not default an extension changed this in my shop. Of cause this is very bad because as you might know a telephone number is not a number.